# django how to get field from child relationship into parent template

Tags: python, django

If I have a one-to-many relationship model. How do i display items from the related child table in my parent template.

models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    child_name = models.CharField()
```

parent.html

```
{% for parent in parents %}

            <tr>
                <td><a href="/get/parent/{{ parent.id }}/">{{ parent.id }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="/parent/get/{{ parent.id }}/">{{ parent.name }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="/parent/get/{{ parent.id }}/">{{ child.child_name }}</a></td>
            </tr>

            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the Django docs on following relationships backwards: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

But basically, it's `parent.child_set.all`

You can change the name `child_set` by adding a `related_name='children'` to the `ForeignKey`: `parent = ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')`

Then you can use: `parent.children.all`